# Why does SQL Server require an aggregate function when grouping by primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE users ( name VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, gender INTEGER );
CREATE TABLE likes ( username VARCHAR(50), object VARCHAR(50) );
```

Now, I want to find out the genders and number of likes for each user

```
SELECT 
    u.name, u.gender, COUNT(*) 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN likes l ON u.name = l.username
GROUP BY u.name
```

Here I'm grouping by the primary key, meaning that there will be exactly one user row per group. However, SQL Server gives me the following error

> Column 'users.gender' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Why is it complaining? Is there a way that I can achieve the desired behavior?

EDIT: Apparently it is the behavior that all the columns without an aggregate function must be added to the `GROUP BY` clause. I guess the true question is: why does it behave this way?

Comment: If you're using `GROUP BY`, **all** columns in your `SELECT` list must be *either* in an aggregate function (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `AVG` etc.), *or* they must be mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause. One or the other - you **cannot have** columns that are neither - whether you're grouping by the primary key or not doesn't matter

Comment: Because you're grouping based on two factors, they must both be specified as the aggregates.  I'm not understanding how what you're wanting to get is different from what you would get by adding the second column to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Adding the second column to the group by clause will not change the output because the first column is the primary key. If I add the second column to the group by clause, will it slow the query down?

Comment: Unless you have millions of records it will not slow things down much. SQL demands you use aggregate functions on all columns that are not in the group by column list. Always has... always will.

Comment: @TheMadDBA iirc MySQL lets you do it. Only when I used SQL Server did it present this error.

Comment: Noone can really answer your last edit of "why does it behave this way" unless they worked at MS and were part of this decision.

Comment: @Strikeskids It behaves this way because you're taking an aggregate.  If you introduce a new column that wasn't in the aggregate to begin with, how would SQL Server know what to display?

Comment: The fact that MySQL allows you to select (non-aggregated) columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` is non standard, and can lead to unexpected results unless you understand what it's doing. Relevant: [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: @sstan . . . Actually, MySQL is modifying the `group by` to be ANSI-compliant in version 5.7.5.  They (and Postgres) will be the only databases (that I know of) that support functional dependencies.

Comment: @Gordon: Thank you very much for the info, and for forcing me to read about functional dependencies :) I didn't know that SQL99 allowed for that.  For those interested: [MySQL 5.7.5: GROUP BY respects functional dependencies!](http://rpbouman.blogspot.nl/2014/09/mysql-575-group-by-respects-functional.html)

Comment: Interesting info about SQL99... I don't usually use MySQL or Postgres but it should be interesting to see when/if SQL Server, Oracle and DB2 support this.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior that you describe is actually consistent with the ANSI standard.  If a group of columns define a unique row, then the other values are "functionally dependent" on those columns.  They can have no other values.  These other columns can be included in the `select` without including them in the `group by`.

The way that functional dependencies are identified and enforced is through primary and unique keys.

So, your desire to only include `name` is quite reasonable.  SQL Server -- and most other databases do not support this (I think the functionality is optional for ANSI-compliance).  Postgres has supported functional dependencies since version 9.1.  MySQL is "fixing" their current `group by` to support this in 5.7.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes and constraints do not affect the valid queries that you can write. This would require logical inference that is possible but not in the standard and not in SQL Server.

Actually, the optimizer does all those inferences. The plan will not have any aggregation at all. This is a language design problem, and they understandably chose not to allow this. It would make for brittle queries and cause almost zero benefit to customers.

Comment: How does the query not make sense?

Comment: The GROUP BY does nothing, remove it.

Comment: That is patently false. Look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3c0c/1 , where I have removed the GROUP BY

Comment: True, I take that back.

Comment: How could the join duplicate rows here?

Comment: likes could contain duplicates.

Comment: `likes` is being aggregated by the `GROUP BY`, so that would not produce a duplicate row. In the query presented, every primary key `users.name` value will appear at most once, meaning there cannot be duplicate rows.

Comment: OK, let me edit this away as well... I hope the rest of the answer kind of helps you.